# Data security in server at home

Tags: linux, internet, gaming, denial-of-service, database-administration

I am a beginner linux user, and am planning on provisionally opening a game server on a machine I have at home. In addition to the possible DDoS attacks that may occur on this server (the server will be open for other people to play) do I run some risk of stealing data and personal information? Is there any way to defend me?

That would be just a temporary situation before I rented a dedicated server.

Comment: As long as the server is run either as a separate container (Docker) or at least a non-privileged user, I can't see any real risk outside of the game being exploited (read: bugs in the game's server)

Comment: Linux has a built-in firewall call iptables.  Accept established traffic.  Forward only the ports necessary for the game drop all the rest.  Then you just have to protect the game server software itself.  Docker or VM or etc.